# Automapper mapping string to list<string> incorrectly

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes

```
 public class SourceClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
}


public class DestinationClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Provider { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping is as follows:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
        memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => 
            new List<string> { src.Provider ?? "" }));
```

Now, previously `Provider` in the DestinationClass was `Providers` and the mapping worked as normal. However, after making the spelling in both classes consistent, the mapping fails to happen properly.

`"Test"` from Source class maps to `["T", "e", "s", "t"]`. When the property names were different in each class, the mapping worked correctly.

Comment: Could possibly be Automapper trying to do this by convention? I was one that commented on your original question. Any particular reason for the rename from `Providers` to `Provider`?

Comment: @TylerHundley thanks for replying! I ended up using the solution you provided. The original name was "Provider" for both and I renamed to Providers as a workaround. However, I'd like to try and change it back to what it was originally

Comment: Is there a reason that the property is a list? If it isn't always a single item I think its clearer when defined as plural

Comment: Upgrade AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used:

- Console Application
- .NET 4.6.1
- the latest stable `Automapper`

Such behaviour is not reproducible:

```
static MapperConfiguration _conf;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var src = new SourceClass() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Provider = "FooProvider" };
    InitializeAutomapper();
    var mapper = _conf.CreateMapper();
    DestinationClass destinationClass = mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(src);
    Console.WriteLine(destinationClass.Provider[0]);
}

static void InitializeAutomapper()
{
    _conf = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
            .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => 
                    new List<string> { src.Provider ?? "" })));
}
```

Output:

```
FooProvider
```